# Spring integration 4 to 5 migration - Issue with integrationGlobalProperties

Tags: spring-integration, spring-properties, spring5

We have been using Spring integration 4.3.1.RELEASE along with Spring core 4.3.2.RELEASE. Recently we had to upgrade the stack with 5.5.11 and 5.3.19 versions resp. This is not a Spring boot app.

After the migration, we are getting below error on start up

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'channelInitializer': Initialization of bean failed; neste
d exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequired
TypeException: Bean named 'integrationGlobalProperties' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties' but was actually of type '
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:177)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:163)
        at com.xxx.xxx.report.listener.generator.ReportListener.main(ReportListener.java:65)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredType
Exception: Bean named 'integrationGlobalProperties' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties' but was actually of type 'com.
sun.proxy.$Proxy37'
        at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:170)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1631)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.doEvaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:280)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:252)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'integrationGlobalProperties' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37'
        at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationContextUtils.obtainUserProperties(IntegrationContextUtils.java:251)
        at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationContextUtils.getIntegrationProperties(IntegrationContextUtils.java:207)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:139)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:95)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:61)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:91)
```

Below is the spring configuration XML we use; we have not configured any bean by the name of 'integrationGlobalProperties' directly -

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="locations">
   <list>
        <value>classpath*:xx.properties</value>
        <value>classpath*:yy.properties</value>
   </list>
</property>
</bean>

<!-- Control channel -->
    <int:channel id="controlChannel" />
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter.........
<int-xml:xpath-router ...........
<int:service-activator..........
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller........
```

Main class is as below -

```
private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context;
public static void main(String[] args) {
String inboundChannel = "cccc";
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/context.xml", ReportListener.class);
MessageChannel controlChannel = context.getBean("controlChannel", MessageChannel.class);
}
```

As per https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/whats-new.html, it is mentioned

```
The integrationGlobalProperties bean (if declared) must be now an instance of  
 org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties instead of java.util.Properties,  
 which support is deprecated for backward compatibility.
```

But we have not explicitly configured this bean; as per documentation, there is a default set of global properties which will be applied if we do not override it.

Could anyone help advise what could be the reason for this exception?

Regards
Jacob

Comment: Seems adding a blank bean definition with id as "integrationGlobalProperties" and class as "org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties" in spring configuration XML fixed the issue. Is this the recommended way?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, it looks like there is some global AOP advice which is applied to this `IntegrationProperties` as well. So, please, revise that part of configuration to make it more specific for exact type of bean you'd like to proxy.

Comment: I have <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> in spring config XML. Corresponding Aspect class is using specific advices like - Around("within(*..*Processor)"), Around("within(*..util.*)"), Around("within(*..services.*)"), Around("within(*..dao.*)"). Not sure how this may be getting applied to IntegrationProperties.

Comment: I’d be glad to investigate if you share some simple project to reproduce and play with. Thanks